# What users do the users in max_user_connections in MySql refer to?

Tags: mysql

In MySql, what users do the users in `max_user_connections` refer to? Does it refer to users as in visitors to the site from outside, or some other kind of users?

I'm a little stuck with this max_user_connections thing. If it's `users` who are visitors to the site how do I set the number? There could be 500 people visiting my site or more or less.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to "handle" this? What are you actually trying to accomplish?  The typical best way to handle it is to leave this value alone.

It refers to the only kind of "user" that MySQL is aware of.

The value of `max_user_connections` establishes a global limit on the number of simultaneous connections by any single **mysql user** for whom you haven't defined an individual connection limit... which typically has nothing at all to do with users on a web site that uses a MySQL server back-end.

Typical web applications use a single MySQL user account for all of their connections to the database.  MySQL users are the users you see when you look here:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

The current connections and the user owning each connection can be seen here:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

This, of course, assumes you havr sufficient privilege to execute these statements.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections